# How to use Selenium on Unity for Android

Tags: c#, selenium, unity-game-engine, selenium-chromedriver

I'm facing an error on Unity for Android.

My Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using UnityCursova;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MainProgram : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public Text FirstText;
    IWebDriver driver;
    void Start()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver(@"Assets/Packages/Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.85.0.0/driver/");
        
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://dekanat.lnu.edu.ua/cgi-bin/classman.cgi?n=999");

        

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Error :

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='Assets/Packages/Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.85.0.0/driver/chromedriver.exe', CommandLine='--port=49237', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You just need to add the name of the executable i.e. **`chromedriver.exe`** to the existing string *`@"Assets/Packages/Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.85.0.0/driver/"`*.

Effectively your line of code will be:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"Assets/Packages/Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.85.0.0/driver/chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: I tried it . but nothing happened(

Comment: @Sviatoslavch Can you confirm that `chromedriver.exe` is stored at `Assets/Packages/Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.85.0.0/driver/`? Is _`(@"Assets/Packages/...`_ a valid location?

Comment: but now there is new error` DriverServiceNotFoundException: The file Assets/Packages/Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.85.0.0/driver/chromedriver.exe\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html`

Comment: it is valid location of chromedriver.exe

Comment: You need to drop `chromedriver.exe` from the mid of `Assets/Packages/Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.85.0.0/driver/chromedriver.exe\chromedriver.exe`. It's mentioned twice.

Comment: Do you happen to know if Selenium can be used to perform a full test automation from the server to the GUI in Unity ? Thanks.